# $P(A \land B) \overset{?}{=} P(A | B)$ when referring to table with values of random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a difference between $P(A \land B)$ and $P(A | B)$ when referring to a table? I know there is a semantic difference since $P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \land B)}{P(B)}$, but when looking at a table the difference doesn't seem so obvious.

For example, in the table below $P(small | +) \overset{?}{=} P(small \land +)$

[image]

Comment: If those eight combinations are equally likely, then $P(small \mid +) = \frac{2}{4}$ since there are $4$ $+$s of which $2$ are *small*, while $P(small \land +) =\frac{2}{8}$ since there are $8$ combinations of which $2$ are *small* and $+$.

Comment: Yes, the combinations are all equally likely. Your explanation makes sense. Essentially, the "given" operator creates a subset of the whole set and the "condition" for that subset is that each value of the "class" random variable must be a "+". Comparatively, the "and" operator considers the entire table (set).